# How would I allow a user to access a specific line in a file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used Python to write a program to open a file and then ask a user input to check if a certain string of characters is in that file.

I am confused on how I would allow the program to print the specific line in which those string of characters they requested for.

That is the part I need help on.

Comment: Check the `in` operator for string

Comment: Can you please show the code you've been using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that the following way:

```
file = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
string = input("Enter string to search in file")
lineCount = 0
for line in file:
    lineCount += 1
    if string in line:
        print(lineCount)
```

Comment: " print the specific line in which those string of characters they requested for" from what I understand the user input can be a substring in the file line. Maybe prefer `if string in line:` rather than `if string == line.rstrip():` as @bigbounty suggested don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I meant to print the whole text in which the string the user requested
Sorry.